# Hints to prove $\overline {A\cap B} = \overline A \cap \overline B$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I've been trying to but also have been stuck on $\overline {A\cap B} \subset \overline A \cap \overline B$ and $\overline A \cap \overline B \subset \overline{A\cap B}$. Any hints to get me started are very appreciated!

The overline here means closure that contains all the limit points.

I totally agree this is FALSE, because the question asks us to prove it first and then give an example when the equality needs not to be true. But I asked my professor and he still specifically ask me to prove it and also give an counter example. :(

Comment: It's false. Consider $A=\{(x,y)|(x-1)^2+y^2<1\}, B=\{(x,y)|(x+1)^2+y^2<1\}$.

Comment: This isn't true. If $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(1,2)$ then $A\cap B=\emptyset$ so $\overline{A\cap B}=\emptyset,$ but $\overline A\cap \overline{B}=\{1\}.$

Comment: Did you mean one of the $\cap$s to be a $\cup$?

Comment: Is it possible that you misunderstood the professor and he wants you to prove or disprove it? Or alternatively that he wants you to repair it to a true statement and prove that?

Comment: I think it is more that my professor didn’t bother double checking the question but just asked me to do what the question asks. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove it sense it is false. Take, in $\mathbb R$ endowed with its usual topology, $A=\mathbb Q$ and $B=\mathbb Q^\complement$. Then $\overline{A\cap B}=\emptyset$, and $\overline A\cap\overline B=\mathbb R$.

However, since $A\cap B\subset A$ and $A\cap B\subset B$, the set $\overline{A\cap B}$ is a subset of both sets $\overline A$ and $\overline B$ and therefore $\overline{A\cap B}\subset\overline A\cap\overline B$.